# .htaccess redirect url ending with

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I redirect url's ending with catalogue.php, for example

> http://www.example.com/catalogue.php

to

> http://www.example.com/all

Not affecting url's like http://www.example.com/catalogue.php?title=titleName&page=2

Tried the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /catalogue.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.example.com/all/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^catalogue\.php$ /all [R=301,L]
```

You will be redirected only if requesting `/catalogue.php`, wthout any query string parameters.

If you need to specify them, you can change the first line to something similar to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !title|titleName|page
```

Here redirect will be done only if none of `title`, `titleName`, `page` parameters specified.

**Added**

If `catalogue.php` may be in subfolder, use:

```
RewriteRule (^|/)catalogue\.php$ /all [R=301,L]
```

You can read more about [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in order to understand how it works.

Comment: `/catalogue.php` redirects to `/all`, `/catalogue.php?title` (Or any other request with query string parameters) doesn't get redirect. You need something else? Please describe the expected result.

Comment: When I go /catalogue.php, url should be redirected only to /all

Comment: When go to /catalogue.php?title, do nothing

Comment: My first code works exactly as you described. When no params specified, page redirects. When at least one (With any name) appears, nothing happens.